# Old "Play Montage" node vs new 'Montage Play" and "Play Anim Montage"

Tags: animation, unreal, blueprints

so.. Following documentation/guides/etc.. I keep coming across the classical node called "Play Montage" which shows one of those Mario Bros pipes as an icon.

However, my version of unreal engine does not have that BP node. it only has "Montage Play" and "Play Anim Montage". As far as I can tell the difference is that there are different input nodes in each of the three cases, and the "Montage Play" is aimed at an Anim instance while the Play Anim Montage is aimed at character.

Could anyone help me out here and illustrate the real difference between all 3? Thank you :)

This is the old one:

[image]

These are the new ones:

[image]